# SQL Rows Multiply with previous generated Value

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone help me to generate the below attached output in SQL SERVER

Excel Formula to generate NAV

=(B2+(B2*A3))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBIBH.png)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow shubham, please let us know you have tried so far.

Comment: Yes, but not able to generate it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Images of data doesn't help us help you; we can't use it. Provide sampled data in a **consumable** format; preferable DDL and DML statements, but at least well formatted tabular `text` or a markdown table. Also don't forget to include your attempts, and if you haven't tried, then at least show what you've done to try to solve the question: What articles/documentation/tutorials/questions did you read to try and help you solve the problem yourself? What about them didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want the function LAG() which gets the value from the previous row.
Please check this example on dbFiddle. Link at the bottom.

> ```
> select 
>   ret "return",
>   coalesce(lag(nav) over (order by inserted_date),100) 
>   + (ret * coalesce(lag(nav) over (order by inserted_date),100) ) "nav",
>   inserted_date
> from t
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>   return |            nav | inserted_date
> -------: | -------------: | :------------
>  0.00000 | 100.0000000000 | 2022-01-10   
>  0.01600 | 101.6000000000 | 2022-01-11   
> -0.00150 | 101.4476000000 | 2022-01-12   
>  0.01030 | 102.4925102800 | 2022-01-13   
>  0.00030 | 102.5232577530 | 2022-01-14   
>  0.00090 | 102.6155309340 | 2022-01-15   
>  0.00000 | 102.6155300000 | 2022-01-16   
>  0.00000 | 102.6155300000 | 2022-01-17   
>  0.09700 | 112.5692364100 | 2022-01-18   
> -0.01660 | 110.7005906160 | 2022-01-19   
> -0.00230 | 110.4459786430 | 2022-01-20   
> -0.00260 | 110.1588104780 | 2022-01-21   
> -0.02820 | 107.0523412760 | 2022-01-22   
>  0.00000 | 107.0523400000 | 2022-01-23   
>  0.00000 | 107.0523400000 | 2022-01-24   
> -0.04560 | 102.1707532960 | 2022-01-25   
>  0.01320 | 103.5194039000 | 2022-01-26   
>  0.00000 | 103.5194000000 | 2022-01-27   
> -0.01020 | 102.4635021200 | 2022-01-28   
>  0.00750 | 103.2319863250 | 2022-01-29   
>  0.00000 | 103.2319800000 | 2022-01-30   
>  0.00000 | 103.2319800000 | 2022-01-31   
>  0.01730 | 105.0178932540 | 2022-02-01   
>  0.00360 | 105.3959644400 | 2022-02-02   
>  0.01180 | 106.6396323280 | 2022-02-03   
> -0.00710 | 105.8824886270 | 2022-02-04
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ff198c655995726140d0125c3ee7de45)*

Comment: `RETURN` is a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @Larnu : thanks - it's simply solved but could be a problem for a newcomer.

Comment: Backticks (`\``) aren't a delimit identifier in T-SQL though, @Kendle . You need to use brackets (`[]`) or double quotes (`"`). You were also missing a right parenthesis (`)`).

Comment: Hi, I want to calculate the NAV to start with 100
Formula to generate Column B = Col B+ (Col B*Col A)

Example:

Col A          Col B( to be Generate)
0.0000        100
0.0160        101.595
-0.0015       101.446
0.0103        102.492
0.0003        102.519
0.0009        102.611

Hope you can understand the question.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Ok - I've changed to lag. Is that what you want?

Comment: The same is not able to generate desired output

Comment: I've added the example. Please check the input and output and try it on DBfiddle.